# Call to undefined method Illuminate\Auth\GenericUser::fill() :: when update

Tags: php, database, laravel, laravel-5

I want to update user password

This is my function:

```
public function modifiermdp(Request $request)
{
    $userupdate = Auth::user();
    $password = bcrypt($request['password']);
    $userupdate->fill(['password' => $password])->save();
    return Redirect::back()->with('message', 'تم التعديل بنجاح');
}
```

This is my route:

```
Route::prefix('/compte')->group(function() {
    Route::get('/', 'CompteController@index');
    Route::post('/changemdp', 'CompteController@modifiermdp');
});
```

And I'm using database driver in config/auth.php

```
'providers' => [
     'enseignant' => [
         'driver' => 'database',
         'table' => 'enseignant',
     ],
],
```

I get this error

> FatalErrorException in CompteController.php line 38:
>   Call to undefined method Illuminate\Auth\GenericUser::fill()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's a database driver, you have to do it manually.

```
\DB::table('enseignant')
    ->where('id', $user->getAuthIdentifier())
    ->update(['password' => $password]);
```

Comment: Same error 

Call to undefined method Illuminate\Auth\GenericUser::forceFill()

Comment: Same error GenericUser::save()

when i use dd($userupdate) 
i get the right information 

GenericUser {#403 ▼
  #attributes: array:21 [▼
    "id" => 1
    "password" => "$2y$10$tWMBS0VEwt7gz.dmT1EHCOolV0lSFqn5dh2.YWJoReMcVNhnH89Dq"
  ]
}

Comment: @cherire just checked the class and it's implementation. Looks like you have to do it manually when it comes to database driver. This is one of the methods inside the database driver user class `public function updateRememberToken(UserContract $user, $token)
    {
        $this->conn->table($this->table)
                ->where('id', $user->getAuthIdentifier())
                ->update(['remember_token' => $token]);
    }`

Comment: Thank you :) 
i didn't know thath before, worked fine